# Incommensurability at an equilateral triangle

Tags: analysis

I want to prove the incommensurability at an equilateral triangle.

The way of such a proof is the following:

1) We are looking for a "common measure" of two lines $ a $, $ b $, i.e. a line $ e $ that measures both $ a $ and $ b $ integer (i.e. there are natural numbers $ m $, $ n $with $ a = me, b = ne $).

2) We take the shorter of the two parts (e.g., $ b $) away from the longer (e.g., $ a $) until the remaining piece $ r_1 $ is shorter than $ b $. We're taking away $ r_1 $ from $ b $ as often as ... and so on.

3) If the process breaks down, there is a common measure, the stretches are then commensurate; otherwise incommensurable.

$$$$

We consider an equilateral triangle ABC with side length $a$. Let CD be the height of the triangle from $C$.

We assume that $ AD $ and $ CD $ have a common $ e $ measure.

Then, for appropriate $ m $ and $ n $: $ AD = ne $ and $ CD = me $.
Now we take the shorter of the two stretches, $ AD $ off the longer, $ CD $, until the remaining $ r_1 $ is shorter than $ AD $.
To do this, we take a circle around the point $ D $ with radius $ AD $, so this intersects the height $ CD $ at point $ E $.

Is this correct so far? How do we continue?

$$$$

Here is a diagramm of a book:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77922/discussion-on-question-by-mary-star-incommensurability-at-an-equilateral-triangl).

Comment: I was summoned here by a system flag raised due to the number of comments. It seemed to me that you had reached a conclusion of some kind. If you want to revisit some of the comments. you can do that in the linked chatroom. If you want a particular comment or two restored for the benefit of future readers, please ID those comments, and then either @-ping me or flag this post explaining the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Everything is either ratios $(1,2,\sqrt3)$ or addition and subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the sides are commensurable, you can multiply all the lengths by an integer factor and assume that $a,b$ are integers. Then the construction gave you a new triangle $A_1C_1D$ (I am looking at the diagram on the left) that is similar to the original one, and that also has integer sides $2a-3b$, $2b-a$, and $2(2b-a)$.

Since $b<a$ and $2b>a$, it follows that $0<DA_1=2b-a<b=AD$. The construction, if you were to repeated with this new smaller triangle, can be repeated indefinitely, strictly reducing the side opposite to the angle of $30$ degrees, and keeping all sides positive integers. That is impossible.

---

A similar construction, that it looks simpler to me:

As in your picture call $b=AD$, $a=CD$, and $CA=2b$. Take $D_1$ on $AC$, with $CD_1=CD$. Then $D_1A=2b-a$. Lift a perpendicular to $AC$ at the point $D_1$ that intersects $AD$ at $F_1$. Since the triangles $ACD$ and $AD_1F_1$ are similar, then $F_1A$ is the double of $D_1A$. Therefore, $F_1A=2(2b-a)$. Subtracting we get that $DF_1=b-2(2b-a)=2a-3b$. Since $F_1D$ and $F_1D_1$ are tangents to the circle with center $C$ and radius $CD$, and both start from the same point $F_1$, then $F_1D_1=F_1D=2a-3b$.

We have obtained a new triangle $AD_1F_1$ that again has integer sides. The side opposite to the angle of $30$ degrees is now $2b-a$ which is positive and strictly less than the one in the original triangle $ACD$, which was $b$.

Comment: Could you explain to me how we get the new sides $A_1$ and $C_1$ ?

Comment: @Mary In my construction or on yours? I will add the full explanation of my construction.

Comment: @MaryStar Added the full explanation of my construction (the second part).

Comment: I understood your construction! I am still facing some difficulties at the construction of my initial post. So we draw a Circle with Center D and Radius AD. This intersects the segment CD at E. Then we draw a circle with Center E and radius EC. This intersects the segment CA at F. Then we take a parallel line to BC from F. This intersects the segment AD at $A_1$. The triangle $AFA_1$ equilateral. Is everything correct so far? Now we have to know the lengths of sides of that triangle to get the length of $A_1D$. How can we determine the length $AA_1$?

Comment: Also how can we determine the length of $C_1D$?